Integrate PKL with other configuration frameworks
My project is using hocon configuration. I would like to migrate it gradually to a PKL. To facilitate a transition period I want to be able to refer to some configuration values from legacy configs.
I tried to implement it by providing a custom resource reader:
import com.typesafe.config.*;
import org.pkl.core.SecurityManagerException;
import org.pkl.core.resource.ResourceReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Optional;

class HoconResourceReader implements ResourceReader {
    private Config config = ConfigFactory.load();
    public Optional<Object> read(URI uri) {
        if (config.hasPath(uri.getSchemeSpecificPart())) {
            var value = config.getAnyRef(uri.getSchemeSpecificPart());
            return Optional.of(value.toString());
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
    public String getUriScheme() { return "hocon"; }
    public boolean hasHierarchicalUris() { return true; }
    public boolean isGlobbable() { return true; }
}


It works well for scalar values (i.e. String). But I need it to be able to provide composite structures (i.e. Dynamic objects with properties).
Is there a way to create an object from a custom value?

One approach I can think of here is to keep your resource reader approach, but have it convert HOCON to JSON, then consume JSON within Pkl. This is because Pkl already has a JSON parser built into the language.
Sample Pkl:
import "pkl:json"

jsonifiedHocon = read("hocon:some.value")

result = new json.Parser {}.parse(jsonifiedHocon)

By the way; hasHierarchicalUris and isGlobbable should both be false.
